# equation to calculate space on label

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a software developer,

I'm working on a rendering PDF report for Android, I have to place a label in the middle of a cell that changes in the X coordinate,

I need to set a cell with some text inside, the text has to be in the middle of the cell, the cell has a fixed width,

this is the relationship of the number of characters with how many spaces of pixels I have to move my label to the right,

so,

- if I have a word or phrase with the maximum number of chars = 40, I add just one pixel
- if I have a word with the minimum number of chars = 3, I add 80 pixels to center the label

the width of my box is fixed, is equal to 181 pixels, I dont think this is needed, just in case,

so how can I come out with an equation to calculate the neccesary number of spaces in pixels to calculate any word? [from 3 to 40 chars]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you represent the number of characters as $x$ and the pixels that must be added as $y$ you have two $(x, y)$ coordinates: $(40, 1)$ and $(3, 80)$. This line has slope $m = \displaystyle \frac{80 - 1}{3 - 40} = -\frac{79}{37}$. To get an equation of the form $y = mx + b$, substitute $x = 40$, $y = 1$, and $\displaystyle m = -\frac{79}{37}$ to solve for $b$: 
\begin{align*}
1 &= -\frac{79}{37}(40) + b \\
1 &= -\frac{3160}{37} + b \\
\frac{3197}{37} &= b
\end{align*}
So the equation for the line is $\displaystyle y = -\frac{79}{37}x + \frac{3197}{37}$. Just plug in the number of characters as $x$ and $y$ will be the number of pixels you must add.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!